# Can't start SSH Agent with Git Bash on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

I have executed the following command in Git Bash, and it returns the following error.

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      1 [main] ssh-agent 1564 child_info_fork::abort: \??\C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\msys- 
crypto-1.1.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x8A0000) != child(0x910000)
fork: Resource temporarily available
```

I have also tried restarting my system, that doesn't do any good.

Any Ideas what this issue is all about, or how to fix it, if possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first in a CMD session to:

- upgrade to the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- the `PATH` correctly set to Git, for testing.

That is:

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

Then, in that same CMD session, type `git bash` and try again